# Presigned URL to Upload Multiple Files to a Path in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload

Is it possible to generate a presigned URL to upload multiple files to a specified path in S3?

Comment: @kv11 Why do you ask? What specific problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein we have a use case where we need to upload multiple images to S3 but don't want the client to call the backend to return a presigned URL multiple times. We could return a list of presigned URLs but the payload would get pretty big and the client may want to upload many images.

Comment: You could instead generate temporary credentials using the AWS Security Token Service (STS), with limited permissions to upload to that S3 bucket. Then, pass those credentials to the client. The client can then use those credentials to upload as many files as they want, without requiring pre-signed URLs. To generate the credentials you would call [`AssumeRole()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html) on an empty role, but provide a Policy specific to the permissions you want to assign to the user, plus a Duration to limit the time that the credentials work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

An [Amazon S3 pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) only provides access to a single object.

Basically, the URL is just like a normal URL that points to an object, but it also contains a calculated 'signature' that verifies your permission to access the object within a fixed time period.